# Create binary package without ports?

Tags: package-management, freebsd, packaging

I am trying to build a binary package on freebsd. All the guides which i am finding are saying basically to build binary package from already installed software using ports. What i am searching for a way to get that done without installing ports.

Is this possible?

My code is in golang. So source contains one binary compiled out of go code and configuration files.

Answer (score 1):

The Documentation of the Packageformat can be found here:
https://wiki.freebsd.org/pkgng#Package_format

You Don't have to install the software to create a Package. during make package in a port, it is installed into a staging directory and then tar'ed up.

Comment: So what you are saying to me is that i should create these additional files. Put everything at one place and tar it. Then running pkg add will install it.

Comment: yes, if you don't want to make a port. But with making a port it is way easier to get everything right